# is it ok to daisy-chain hot wire to multiple switches in same box?

Tags: electrical, switch

Making a few changes in an existing 4-gang switch box, I notice the original electrician did some things that seem a little funky.   The various neutral and hot wires are just twisted together with a crimp ring and taped, but no wirenut.   I can easily, and will, add wirenuts.   But ... there is a pigtail coming from the bundle of hots, and it goes to two different switches, with a little insulation stripped off where it's screwed to the first switch, and then the stripped end screwed to the second switch in the usual fashion.    I'd rather leave these two switches alone, as they have nothing to do with the changes I'm making (to one of the other two switches).   Is this ok ?   This work will not be inspected, but I want to do the right thing.

Comment: What you are describing is code compliant. In my early days as an electrician crimps were required on the grounds and many electricians used crimps on the neutrals with tape. The only problem with crimps is if rewring most just cut the wire off then it is a bit short but crimps are still 100% legal on both current varying and grounded conductors

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.    But what about the hot wire daisy-chained to two different switches (instead of separate pigtails, from the bundle of hots, going to each switch) ?

Comment: As tester mentions below when close to the maximum fill sometimes we will daisy chain with a wire stripped in the center with #14 wire this saves 2 cubic inches of space compared to running both switches back to the pigtail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem with the wiring methods you've described.  Using a single wire, reduces the number of wires in a slice. This can come in handy when trying to reduce the number of wires in a twist on wire connector.